# What is a DispatcherFrame and how do I use it?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

Here's the code provided by [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherframe(v=vs.110).aspx), although it doesn't appear to be clear on what it's doing:

```
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
public void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}

public object ExitFrame(object f)
{
    ((DispatcherFrame)f).Continue = false;

    return null;
}
```

I've just noticed a similar implementation in some legacy code today where the `DoEvents` method was defined. Why do we need this and what does it mean to push a frame onto the dispatcher?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33008093/1136211).

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502037/where-is-the-application-doevents-in-wpf