# What is a DispatcherFrame in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, message-queue, dispatcher

Maybe someone can explain what a DispatcherFrame is. Other posts and the MS Docs' description is in my opinion not detailed enough:

> Represents an execution loop in the Dispatcher.

Does this mean it is blocking the message queue in some way?

thanks;

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33002966/1136211

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769483/17034

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a `DispatcherFrame` as something that forces operations to be processed until some condition is met (or the application is shut down). Please refer to [Kent Boogaart's blog post](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/dispatcher-frames) on the subject for more information and a [downloadable sample](https://kent-boogaart.com/assets/2008-04-28-dispatcher-frames/DoEvents.zip).

Comment: After a Frame has finished his work (message queue is empty) do I have to set up a whole new frame? When is the message queue in a wpf app empty?